# Error message = Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc-test

Testing a spring file upload form, the controlelr signature looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {}
```

and the test this

```
final MockMultipartFile file 
  = new MockMultipartFile("content", "myFile.txt", "text/plain", "hello".getBytes());

MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockHttpServletRequestBuilder = 
  .fileUpload("/upload/")
  .file(file)
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

but I get the aforementioned : *Error message = Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present*

Comment: You named it "content" when calling the constructor in your test.

Comment: @Bart thankyou, thats fifteen minutes of my life I will never get back

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You named the parameter as "file" and not as "content":

Change:

```
new MockMultipartFile("content", "myFile.txt", "text/plain", "hello".getBytes());
```

To:

```
new MockMultipartFile("file", "myFile.txt", "text/plain", "hello".getBytes());
```