# Spring-Boot + Tomcat 8.0.3 FileUpload error Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Tags: file-upload, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a working spring-boot mvc application where i am trying integrate a file upload option. As per manual I have configured the following template:

/src/main/resource/templates/fileUpload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html layout:decorator="layout">

<head> 
<title>syncServer File upload example</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">

    <div >
        <form th:action="@{/upload}" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:method="post">
            <fieldset>
                     <legend>File to upload:</legend>
                     <input type="file" name="myFile" />
                     <label>Name :</label>
                     <input type="text" name="myName"/>
                     <input type="submit" />
            </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

when i login and then call http:/127.0.0.5:8080/upload the form displays but when i click the submit button i got. the error message

> HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request
>   parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

The i went and disable csrf in order to see if the form will simply work if the cross site request forgery is disabled (".csrf().disable()"). 
i.e.

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
//          .headers().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/css/**","/register", "/resources/img/**" , "/resources/js/**", "/resources/pdf/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

When i tried to upload a another file during the csrf was disabled i got another error i.e.:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no
>   multi-part configuration has been provided

it says "no multi-part configuration has been provided" but i do have configuration file that configures the multipartConfigElement i.e.

```
@Configuration
public class FileUpload {
    @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("600KB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("600KB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
}
```

I have also the @ComponentScan anotation and the @EnableAutoConfiguration above my Application class i.e.:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.syncServer.*")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
}
```

When the application starts i am listing all the beans that are managed by spring and i do see that the bean "multipartResolver" is being initiated.

Controller associated with the fileUpload.html:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String provideUploadInfo() {
        return "fileUpload";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("myName") String myName, 
            @RequestParam("myFile") MultipartFile myFile){
        if (!myFile.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = myFile.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = 
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(myName + "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "Successfully uploaded " + myName + " into " + myName + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Failed to upload " + myName + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "Failed to upload " + myName + " empty file.";
        }
    }

}
```

When i set a breakpoint at the get method i see that the method is hit and it returns the fileUpload.html view. However the post method is not hit at all.

I do not know if that is relevant but i have set in Project-Properties-Deployment assembly - /src/main/resources as "/" this is the only entry i have in my Deployment Assembly configuration.

I have read before that there was a bug in old spring-boot RC version with the file uploads. I am currently using the spring-boot 1.0.2.RELEASE. 
My pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>sync</groupId>
    <artifactId>syncServer</artifactId>
    <name>syncServer</name>

    <!-- When removing the parent project configuration you have to explicitly set the dependencies version -->
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat8.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>



    </build>



  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>


    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <spring-version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <start-class>org.syncServer.core.Application</start-class>
        <springBootVersion>1.0.2.RELEASE</springBootVersion>
        <tomcat8.version>8.0.3</tomcat8.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hibernate>4.3.1.Final</hibernate>
    </properties>



</project>
```

Addition here is the full html code as requested in the comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
  <head>
<title>Task List - syncServer File upload example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/syncServer.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>



</head>

  <body>
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My project</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/message">OpenSource</a></li>
            <li><a href="/task">Documents</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<!--             <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')}"> -->
<!--               <a href="/signin" th:href="@{/signin}">Sign in</a> -->
<!--             </li> -->
<!--             <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}"> -->
<!--               <a href="/logout" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a> -->
<!--             </li> -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>

    <div>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/upload">
            <fieldset>
                     <legend>File to upload:</legend>
                     <input type="file" name="myFile" />
                     <label>Name :</label>
                     <input type="text" name="myName" />
                     <input type="submit" />
            </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>

    </div>
      <div>
      © 2014
      <br />
      Autumn, Winter, Summer , Spring is always inside.
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Addition 2 link to the working maven project showing the problem

```
https://github.com/TheDictator/sArchitecture
```

in order to reproduce login with:

user name: admin2 password: #passworD

and go to

```
http://127.0.0.5:8080/upload
```

the error message described above is see.

Addition 3

My particular problem is fixed when i removed the bean that i have previously declared before the entry point mail in the application class i.e.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {

    System.out.println("SERVLET REGISTRATION");
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            dispatcherServlet());

    System.out.println("SERVLET REGISTERED NAME is: "
            + registration.getServletName().toString());
    registration.addUrlMappings("/");

    return registration;
}
```

I have not answered this question my self as i do not yet understand why this peace of code is messing up the upload functionality.

Comment: Does it work with tomcat 7?

Comment: hello Dave thank you for the replay. i run the test today with eApache Tomcat/7.0.53 and it is also not working, this time i get the error "HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'myFile' is not present".

Comment: relevant post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833683/error-message-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-present

Comment: I have found similar errors in SO but i still do not see any error with my code

Comment: What about the [getting started guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files)? Does that work for you (does for me)?

Comment: Yes it does, actually the code i post in this question is based on the guide you send, the only change i made is the thymeleaf html form and the factory.setMaxFileSize("600KB"); My form looks right thou, the setMaxFileSize ig bigger. I have the feeling that this is some chaching issue. i.e. i have in the application.properties spring.thymeleaf.cache: false
server.tomcat.access_log_enabled: true

Comment: Can you paste in the source HTML from your browser after thymeleaf has rendered it?

Comment: Hello Dave just posted at the end of the question the source of the html.

Comment: That looks fine. My best guess: the "multipartConfigElement" is not being created, Is it part of a `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: Hello Dave, the "multipartConfigElement" is instanticated by the factory at the boot time. I have made the test without it and with it. I can see clearlly that this bean is initicated. I  try to  create a simple maven project and post it on github showing my problem and then post the link here.

Comment: Hello Dave, i have uploaded on github (details in the end of the questions description) a working maven project  that shows the upload error message that i get. Any feedback regarding this behavior is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the project link. I can't run it because I don't have the keystore (I think). Anyway a much smaller application could reproduce this problem, so it might be worth your while to create one.

Comment: ok i found what was my particular problem. i.e. it was the ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration()  bean that i registered before the application entry point i.e. the main(). When i remove that bean the application works as it should. Although that fixed my problem if anybody can explain why this bean was messing up the upload functionality i would greatly appreciate it. I have posted the full code of the  dispatcherRegistration()  bean at the end of the question description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register the `DispatcherServlet` yourself (instead of letting Spring Boot do it) so you have to take care to add the multipart configuration for it. Spring Boot only adds multipart configuration to the `ServletRegistrationBeans` that it creates itself ([see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java#L263)) so if you create your own you have to take care of it. Hopefully the API of `ServletRegistrationBean` is clear enough that this is implied, if not obvious